# COM Client (VBScript) Handling C# .NET Remoting Event

Tags: c#, events, vbscript, com-interop, .net-remoting

I am developing a plug-in to an existing program, and am trying to add a COM interface.  In order to reference the instances of the various objects which are instantiated by the plugin, the plugin also serves as a .NET Remoting server for cross-process communication.  The .NET Remoting client code is also contained within the same library, which is installed in the GAC.  (I understand that WCF has replaced .NET Remoting as the go-to solution, but for various reasons WCF isn't really an option.)

The COM consumer (VBScript, in my case) creates an object on the client-side, which then obtains references to the server-side objects (MarshalByRefObject).  This all works wonderfully, and I am able to interact with the objects which interface with the host application.

I am unable, however, to correctly handle events on objects that cross the application domain boundary.

I have the following defined:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public delegate void TestEventHandler();

[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface ITestEvent
{
    [DispId(5)]
    void OnTestEvent();
}

[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ITestEvent))]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("Zedd.TestEvent")]
public class TestEvent : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public event TestEventHandler OnTestEvent;

    public TestEvent() { }

    public void DoTest()
    {
        if (OnTestEvent != null)
        {
            OnTestEvent.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("Zedd.TestEventPassthrough")]
public class TestPassthrough : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public TestPassthrough() { }

    public TestEvent GetTestEvent()
    {
        return new TestEvent();
    }
}
```

If I create a `TestPassthrough` object from the VBScript, I can successfully handle the event:

```
DIM testPassthrough
DIM testEventObj
SET testPassthrough = CreateObject("Zedd.TestEventPassthrough")
SET testEventObj = testPassthrough.GetTestEvent()
Wscript.ConnectObject testEventObj, "testEventObj_"
testEventObj.DoTest()

SUB testEventObj_OnTestEvent
    Wscript.Echo "Successfully Handled The Event."
END SUB
```

I see "Successfully Handled The Event." as expected.

If, however, I use .NET Remoting to get an existing reference, I get an error: "WScript.CreateObject: Could not connect object."

```
DIM remotingClient
DIM testPassthrough
DIM testEventObj
SET remotingClient = CreateObject("Zedd.TestClient")

' This returns a TestPassthrough object reference, which has crossed the boundary.
SET testPassthrough = remotingClient.TestPassthrough

SET testEventObj = testPassthrough.GetTestEvent()

' This is the line where the error occurs: "WScript.CreateObject: Could not connect object."
WScript.ConnectObject testEventObj, "testEventObj_"

testEventObj.DoTest()

SUB testEventObj_OnTestEvent
    Wscript.Echo "Successfully Handled The Event."
END SUB
```

What do I need to do to my TestEvent class so that its events are accessible when passing through the application domain boundary?

Comment: It is a messy mix, .NET does remoting, so does COM.  But of course not the same way.  Starkly different to put it mildly.  There is no scenario where you can have COM client subscribe an event of a remote .NET object.  You'll need to re-fire it locally.

Comment: What would it look like to "re-fire it locally"?